# Python Programming Multiple Choice

Tags: python

I was studying for a CS common exam, and I was doing a few practice tests. I couldn't understand why this question returned "=" instead of "False". I really don't understand

```
splitLine = aStr.split()

def mostlyLongWords(aStr, threshold):
    splitLine = aStr.split()
    shortCount = 0
    longCount = 0
    for word in splitLine:
        if len(word) < threshold:
            shortCount += 1
        else:
            longCount += 1
        if shortCount > longCount:
            return False
        if longCount > longCount:
            return True
    return '='
seussLine = 'There is no one alive who is you-er than you'
print(mostlyLongWords(seussLine, 5))
```

a. True
b. False
c. =
d. SyntaxError:incompatible return types
e. None of the above

Comment: It returns False to me

Comment: It will return `False` try executing it

Comment: where you define `aStr` in first line. if delete first line return `False` for me too.

Comment: Write down "import pdb;pdb.set_trace()" at the entry of your function:  and debug it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've copied that faithfully, this is a trick question. There are two serious bugs in the code, that cause it to not act as expected, and you're presumably supposed to find those bugs.

What you'd *like* it to do is count up the number of short and long words, and return `False`, `'='`, or `True` depending on how they compare. Since the test sentence has 7 short words and 3 long, it should return `False`.

But the `if` checks are indented *inside* the `for` loop. That means that, instead of doing the check after all the words have been counted up, you're doing it after every single word. So as soon as there's an imbalance, `1 > 0`, and therefore you're just checking whether the first word is long, not whether most of the words are long. Since `'There'` is long (5 or more characters), it should return `True`.

But there's *another* mistake; The second comparison is not `longCount > shortCount`, it's `longCount > longCount`. That's obviously never going to be true. So, the program will loop until either the number of short words pulls ahead of the number of long words—in which case it will return `False`—or it will just fall out of the loop and return `'='`. In this case, as soon as you get to the word `'no'`, `shortWords` is `2`, `longWords` is `1`, therefore it returns `False`.

If the correct answer was supposed to be `=`, then either you didn't copy it faithfully, or the answer is just wrong. One possibility is that there's a third bug that you unwittingly corrected while copying the question over. For example, I notice that you've got a `splitLine = aStr.split()` *outside* the function. That's a strange thing to do, and it ought to be a `NameError`. But if there's a line like, say, `aStr = ''` somewhere earlier in the code that you haven't shown us, then you'd be setting a valid global variable named `splitLine`. And if there's a typo in the actual code like, say, `splitline = aStr.split()`, then your function would be looping over that global variable. If it were, say, `''.split()`, or `'There there'`, then, in combination with the other two bugs, that would lead to `'='` being returned.